# Does SDL2 work properly with OpenGL 3.2 core?

Tags: opengl, sdl

I have a problem with my project and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong exactly. I've been searching all over but I can't find definite conformation that SDL2 works with OpenGL 3.2 core. I just need to check this off as one of the possible problems. So does it work with OpenGL 3.2 core and is there anything special I need to know?

Comment: Are you initializing the 3.2 entrypoints (perhaps using GLEW) after creating the context with SDL?

Comment: Yes, I am and it only works if I use glewExperimental = GL_TRUE. Not sure why that is though.

Comment: I should clarify. It does not report any errors if I use glewExperimental = GL_TRUE but it still does not work...

Comment: It does, in fact there is a nice tutorial here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial1:_Creating_a_Cross_Platform_OpenGL_3.2_Context_in_SDL_(C_/_SDL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SDL does work with OpenGL 3.2. The library I was using called CG toolkit does not appear to work with a core profile which was causing my problems but no one seems to know for sure if CG can work with a core profile.